# Can i get applied style Object of editor-text in textangular

Tags: angularjs, textangular

i want to save **textangular** editor's text with styles and tags (applied by its toolbar) in DB. 
Is there a way i can do this without saving `HTML` ?
Currently i am saving html with decoding.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to store the html?

Comment: @charlietfl i want to get the styles (tags) that are applied on specific text-angular field and only want to store those tags.

Comment: That really isn't very clear. Provide example